# How to minimize $ x $ subject to $ y \le x^3$ and $y \ge 0 $

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have been getting into NLP, the Karush Kuhn Tucker theorem and the Linear Independence Constraint Qualification and I came across this problem.

My first attempt was to solve graphically and I found the feasible solution to be  $ (x,y) = (0,0) $, but I think the KKT theorem and the LICQ conditions fail at this point, can anybody help me on how to check if the conditions hold? Thanks!

Comment: Ummm... $x=y=0$?  And KKT is irrelevant at the boundary of a solution region (here $x=0$).

Comment: That I solved graphically, but I wanted to know if the KKT and LICQ conditions are verified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$
\begin{align}
h_1(x, y) &= x^3 - y \\
h_2(x, y) &= y
\end{align}
$$
Such that we can state our problem as 
$$
\underset{x, y}{\arg \min} \, x \\
\text{subject to } \begin{array}{c}
h_1(x, y) \geq 0 \\
h_2(x, y) \geq 0 
\end{array}
$$
We identified the optimal point as $(0, 0)$ and inspec the gradients $\nabla h_1$, $\nabla h_2$ at that point
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla h_1(x, y) &= (3x^2, -1) \\
\nabla h_2(x, y) &= (0, 1)
\end{align}
$$
which inserted for $(0, 0)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla h_1(0, 0) &= (0, -1) \\
\nabla h_2(0, 0) &= (0, 1)
\end{align}
$$
which are not linearly independent. Now both constraints are active $h_1(0, 0)= 0$ and $h_2(0, 0) = 0$ but their gradients are not linearly independent and LICQ does not hold.

Comment: Thanks! And for the KKT, since the LICQ does not hold the KKT also does not hold either?

Comment: True. If LICQ does not hold, then the minimum may be found at a place that does not satisfy the KKT conditions.